# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide return n/db/n.sum(), bin_edges

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph based on the few data that I have but I have encountered some issues. Here are the codes that I have tried

```
import sqlite3
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

q5 = c.execute('''
SELECT AVG(ontime.ArrDelay) AS Avg_ArriveDelay,
   ontime.Month AS MonthArrive,
   ontime.Year AS YearArrive
FROM ontime
WHERE ontime.Cancelled = 0 AND 
  ontime.Diverted = 0 AND 
  ontime. ArrDelay > 0
GROUP BY MonthArrive,YearArrive
ORDER BY YearArrive ASC, MonthArrive ASC
''').fetchall()
q5 = pd.DataFrame (q5, columns = ['Avg_ArriveDelay','MonthArrive','YearArrive'])
pd.DataFrame(q5)
```

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist([q5.loc[q5.YearArrive == class_idx, "MonthArrive"] for class_idx in range(1,3)], density = True, label=['2004', '2005'])
ax.set_ylabel("Average_ArrDelay")
ax.set_xlabel("Month/Year")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

However, this is the error I am facing. RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
return n/db/n.sum(), bin_edges
[image]
I wanted my x-axis to contain the 12 different months of data separated into 2 different years, and my y-axis displaying the average delay per month/year. Thanks in advance

@JohanC
Hi! I have attempted using the 2nd suggestion you provided. With these following codes. Is there anyway I can put it side by side?

```
ax = sns.histplot(data=q5, x='MonthArrive', hue='YearArrive',
  y='Avg_ArriveDelay', stat='frequency', multiple='dodge', discrete=True)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 13))
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image]

@JohanC Hi! So I decided to use bar plot instead and used the following codes below

```
AverageDelay = q5.groupby(['Month','Year']).size().unstack()
AverageDelay.columns = ["2004", "2005"]
AverageDelay.index = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
AverageDelay.plot(kind='bar', stacked = False, ylabel = "AverageDelay", xlabel = "Months/Year", title = "Average Delay in different Months/Year");
```

However, this is what i am seeing.
[image]
Is there anyway I can adjust the y axis?

Comment: @JohanC apparently I want it to look like the graph right above, however the above graph do not work as it is a histogram and not a bar graph which is what I am doing now, is there any place or at the code where I can add in the y axis as =“Avg_ArriveDelay”

Answer (score 0):

To answer the new question about drawing a bar plot:

You need to make the sum of the 'Avg_ArriveDelay' column and plot that. If you use `.size()`, pandas will just count the number of values, which apparently is exactly one of each.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

q5 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': np.repeat([2004, 2005], 12),
                   'Month': np.tile(np.arange(1, 13), 2),
                   'Avg_ArriveDelay': np.random.uniform(10, 30, 24) })
AverageDelay = q5.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])['Avg_ArriveDelay'].sum().unstack()

AverageDelay.index = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
AverageDelay.plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, ylabel="AverageDelay", xlabel="Months/Year",
                  title="Average Delay in different Months/Year", rot=0, figsize=(12, 5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas bar plot]

Here is an answer to your original question:

The problem is the test `q5.YearArrive == class_idx` using `for class_idx in range(1,3)`.  The dataframe shown only has values `2004` and `2005` for `q5.YearArrive`, while `range(1,3)` are the values `1` and `2`. This makes that you try to create a histogram from an empty set.

A solution would be to collect the valid values for years (`classes = q5['YearArrive'].unique()` and use that for the `class_idx`.

Another problem is that the months are discrete, while a default histogram is meant for continuous values. The default bin edges would be 10 steps from the lowest to the highest value, so from `1` to `12`, or `[ 1,  2.1,  3.2,  4.3,  5.4,  6.5,  7.6,  8.7,  9.8, 10.9, 12]`. This would throw together months 1 and 2 into the same bin, as well as months 11 and 12. All the others would go in separate bins. This can be solved by choosing bins nicely in-between the month values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

q5 = pd.DataFrame({'YearArrive': np.repeat([2004, 2005], 50),
                   'MonthArrive': np.random.randint(1, 13, 100)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
classes = q5['YearArrive'].unique()
ax.hist([q5.loc[q5['YearArrive'] == class_idx, "MonthArrive"] for class_idx in classes], bins=np.arange(0.5, 13),
        density=True, label=classes, color=['crimson', 'dodgerblue'])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 13))
ax.legend()
ax.margins(x=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram from years and months]

Another approach would use seaborn, which creates the classes and the bins more automatically:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

q5 = pd.DataFrame({'YearArrive': np.repeat([2004, 2005], 50),
                   'MonthArrive': np.random.randint(1, 13, 100)})

ax = sns.histplot(data=q5, x='MonthArrive', hue='YearArrive', stat='density',
                  multiple='dodge', discrete=True)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 13))
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot]

Comment: Hi! I have attempted it with the 2nd suggestion you provided, is there any way for it to be side by side? instead of top and bottom

Comment: Hi! I realised my mistake after clarifying with my professor and he said the same thing as you, I’ll be trying out with bar plot instead, thanks so much :)

Comment: is there anyway i can adjust the y axis? I've updated the latest version right below the attached post